# Azure Sql Database query

Tags: xamarin.ios, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I have created a Database on Azure
I am also able to access Azure Sql database from my local server by setting firewall etc

What I notice is when I do a table schema change e.g Create a new table or add a new column to an existing table, the changes do not reflect on the Azure App (although I can see the latest table changes on Azure SQL database Query editor)

I tried modifying sample TODO app which Azure provide with a default TODO table.

After downloading the App from Azure and running it, App runs without any issues by loading proper data from TODO table.

But when I add a new column/rename column to the existing TODO table, Changes DOT file to add new column in api service and published the service. APP stops displaying data with connection error...

```
{Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException: The request could not be completed.  (Internal Server Error)
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<ThrowInvalidResponse>d__24.MoveNext () [0x001da] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<SendRequestAsync>d__26.MoveNext () [0x000fc] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceHttpClient+<RequestAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x000f0] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<ReadAsync>d__20.MoveNext () [0x0009c] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceTable+<ReadAsync>d__18.MoveNext () [0x00136] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider+<Execute>d__8`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000b2] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQueryProvider+<Execute>d__7`1[T].MoveNext () [0x000a2] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Query.MobileServiceTableQuery`1+<ToListAsync>d__33[T].MoveNext () [0x00068] in <bac65eb8c7d1436299ebf8569aaf78b5>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.4.0.93/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in <e1bdc71e0615425d8d4ddf5cd7e37d8e>:0 
  at MyApp08112017.QSCustomerViewController+<RefreshDataAsync>d__9.MoveNext () [0x0008c] in E:\Workspaces\ATM Project\ZIPs From Azure\MyApp08112017_Xamarin_iOS\MyApp08112017\QSCustomerViewController.cs:33 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> at MyApp08112017.QSCustomerViewController+d__9.MoveNext () [0x0008c] in E:\Workspaces\ATM Project\ZIPs From Azure\MyApp08112017_Xamarin_iOS\MyApp08112017\QSCustomerViewController.cs:33 }

Based on the error message, you are using the C# backend for your Azure Mobile Apps. For adding a new table, you need to define the model of your table and create a Table Controller for it. For edit the column(s), you could edit the table model. Before publishing your backend to azure, you need to implement code first migrations, you could manually create the migration file via `add-migration` and leverage the command `update-database` to apply the existing migration. Also, you could enable the automatically code first migrations. More details, you could refer to adrian hall's book [Implementing Table Controllers](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/). Moverover, you could also check [Handling Publish Failures](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/server/#handling-publish-failures).